# Migrating from ngx-bootstrap v5.12 to v6.2.0

Tags: angular, angular9, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to migrate from ngx-bootstrap v5.1.2 to v.6.2.0, getting errors mentioned below

```
const initalState = { rate: number, title: Title};
const modalOptions: ModalOptions = { ignoreBackdropClick: true, initialState };
```

Type '{ rate: number; title: Title; }' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<`Object`>'.
`initialState?: Partial<T>`

Comment: That's all that I've had to change. Are you having a specific issue?

Comment: I am getting error with " initialState " property, ngx-bootstrap v5.1.2 had initialState of type Object, now(v6.2.0) it is of type " Partial<T> ". How to fix this?

Comment: You'll have to add some code to your question because it's difficult to help you without seeing the actual problem you're having.

Comment: Yeah, it was changed, but, I also would like to see the full code, because [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component) it works correctly.

Also, I see that you declare `initalState` and then used `initialState`, maybe just a typo, but, who knows